# React-Native: Connect to PHP api using hooks for user login

Tags: javascript, php, react-native, api, backend

How can I connect to my php api using hooks so that a user can login. I can't find where I'm going wrong. I'm new to using hooks, also is there a way I can implement more than one onChangeText to textInput so I can keep my remaining functions. I'm trying to connect to an sql database so that a user can login. I've also tried using node.js and express but had no success. Any help tr guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

```
UserLoginFunction = () =>{
 
    const { email }  = this.state ;
    const { password }  = this.state ;
    
    
   fetch('https://localhost/api,login.php', {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     },
     body: JSON.stringify({
    
       email: email,
    
       password: password
    
     })
    
   }).then((response) => response.json())
         .then((responseJson) => {
    
           // If server response message same as Data Matched
          if(responseJson === 'Data Matched')
           {
    
                 AsyncStorage.setItem('user', res.user);
               //Then open Profile activity and send user email to profile activity.
               this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', { Email: email });
    
           }
           else{
    
             Alert.alert(responseJson);
           }
    
         }).catch((error) => {
           console.error(error);
         });
    
     }


const SignInScreen = ({navigation}) => {

    state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
      };

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
   

    const [data, setData] = React.useState({
            email:'',
            password: '',
            check_textInputChange: false,
            secureTextEntry: true
    });

    const {signIn} = React.useContext(AuthContext);

    const textInputChange = (val) => {
        if(val.length != 0) {
            setData({
                ...data,
                email: val,
                check_textInputChange: true
            });
        } else {
            setData({
                ...data,
                email: val,
                check_textInputChange: false
            });
        }
    }

    const handlePasswordChange = (val) => {
        setData({
            ...data,
            password: val
        });
    }

    const updateSecureTextEntry = () => {
        setData({
            ...data,
            secureTextEntry: !data.secureTextEntry
        })
    }

   const componentDidMount = () => {
        this._loadInitialState().done();
    }

   const _loadInitialState = async () => {
        var value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
        if(value !== null){
            this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
        }
    }

    /*User Interface*/

    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor='#009387' barStyle='dark-content'/>
        <View style={styles.header}>
            <Text style={styles.text_header}>Welcome!</Text>
        </View>
        <Animatable.View style={styles.footer}  
            animation="fadeInUpBig"
        >
            <Text style={styles.text_footer}>Email</Text>
            <View style={styles.action}>
                <FontAwesome name="user-o" color="#ffdf2b" size={20} />
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Your Email"
                    placeholderTextColor = "#7a6b02"
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    /* first onChangeText stops working when second once is implemented */
                    onChangeText={(val)=>textInputChange(val)}
                    
                />
                {data.check_textInputChange ? 
                <Animatable.View  animation="bounceIn">
                <Feather
                    name="check-circle"
                    color="green"
                    size={20}
                />
                </Animatable.View>
                : null}
            </View>
            <Text style={[styles.text_footer, {marginTop: 45}]}>Password</Text>
            <View style={styles.action}>
            <FontAwesome name="lock" color="#ffdf2b" size={20} />
            <TextInput
                placeholder="Your Password"
                placeholderTextColor = "#7a6b02"
                secureTextEntry={data.secureTextEntry ? true : false}
                style={styles.textInput}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                onChangeText={(val)=> handlePasswordChange(val)}
                onChangeText={password => setPassword(password)}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={updateSecureTextEntry}>
            {data.secureTextEntry ? 
            <Feather
                name="eye-off"
                color="grey"
                size={20}
            />
            :
            <Feather
            name="eye"
            color="grey"
            size={20}
             />  }
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.button}> 

        
             <TouchableOpacity style={styles.signIn} onPress={this.login} >
             <LinearGradient colors={['#ffdf2b', '#cfb504']} style={styles.signIn}>
                <Text style={[styles.textSign,{color:'#161616'}]}>Sign In</Text>
                </LinearGradient>
                </TouchableOpacity>
             

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SignUpScreen')} style={[styles.signIn, 
                { borderColor: '#ffdf2b', borderWidth:1, marginTop:20}]}>
            <Text style={[styles.textSign,{color:'#ffdf2b'} ]}>Sign Up</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        </Animatable.View>
        </View>
    );
};
```

My PHP api

```
//Define your host here.
$HostName = "localhost";
 
//Define your database name here.
$DatabaseName = "root";
 
//Define your database username here.
$HostUser = "root";
 
//Define your database password here.
$HostPass = "Lcfckid1!";
 

// Creating connection.
 $con = mysqli_connect($HostName,$HostUser,$HostPass,$DatabaseName);
 
 // Getting the received JSON into $json variable.
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
 
 // decoding the received JSON and store into $obj variable.
 $obj = json_decode($json,true);
 
// Populate User email from JSON $obj array and store into $email.
$email = $obj['email'];
 
// Populate Password from JSON $obj array and store into $password.
$password = $obj['password'];
 
//Applying User Login query with email and password match.
$Sql_Query = "select * from user where email = '$email' and password = '$password' ";
 
// Executing SQL Query.
$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$Sql_Query));
 
 
if(isset($check)){
 
 $SuccessLoginMsg = 'Data Matched';
 
 // Converting the message into JSON format.
$SuccessLoginJson = json_encode($SuccessLoginMsg);
 
// Echo the message.
 echo $SuccessLoginJson ; 
 
 }
 
 else{
 
 // If the record inserted successfully then show the message.
$InvalidMSG = 'Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again' ;
 
// Converting the message into JSON format.
$InvalidMSGJSon = json_encode($InvalidMSG);
 
// Echo the message.
 echo $InvalidMSGJSon ;
 
 }
 
 mysqli_close($con);
?>
```